# Is it normal for GPU to overheat during boot with fans running max

Tags: boot, nvidia, fan

I cant measure how hot it gets during boot but then in desktop after launch it cools down rapidly
NVIDIA rtx 3060 ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, yes, within reason.

After reset, no power-saving mechanisms are enabled. They are enabled later on, usually by the driver loaded by the operating system.